# IOS guided access - can app know it is in guided access mode?

Tags: ios, guided-access

I am developing an IOS app for a class room environment - conducting a test.  I have a requirement that the app should not come out during the test. Guided access is a perfect solution for me, since I can force users (students) to turn the device to guided access mode.

What I want is like this: Only after the device is set into guided access mode, the app will proceed from a particular screen.  Is it possible for the app to know (programmatically) whether the device is in guided access mode at any point in time?  Any documentation available on this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: This is the first question listed under the "Related" section. Please check those before posting a question. It helps to avoid such duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

I found a feasible solution.  IOS 6 (onwards) has a method: UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled.  Returns a Boolean value indicating whether Guided Access is enabled.

It is in Apple's [UIKit Reference Manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityIsGuidedAccessEnabled)